# Conflicting return types of std::set iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, auto, const-iterator

This is the second compiler error today that has gotten me confused.   Somehow for the code below, gcc complains that the code has the function which returns an iterator `return_iter` return conflicting types `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<const int*>` and then `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<const int*>`, but both of them should not be const iterators because the set is not const.  Could anyone explain why the `std::end()` method when called on a non const lvalue returns a `const_iterator`?

The complete code is pasted below.

**Note** I only get this error when compiling with `gcc`.  This error does not show up when I compile this with clang (`Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)`.  The gcc version I am using is `g++ (GCC) 5.1.0`

A related question.  Is this the correct use of forward?  Is it considered ok to call `std::forward` whenever you want to use a forwarding reference?  The reason I have it called below is just in case the type overloads some methods for when the object is an rvalue..

---

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int global_value = 1;

class LessPtr {
public:

    template <typename PointerComparableOne, typename PointerComparableTwo>
    constexpr auto operator()(PointerComparableOne&& lhs,
                              PointerComparableTwo&& rhs) const {
        return *std::forward<PointerComparableOne>(lhs) <
            *std::forward<PointerComparableTwo>(rhs);
    }

    using is_transparent = std::less<void>::is_transparent;
};

template <typename Container, typename Key>
auto return_iter(Container&& container, Key&& key) {
    if (global_value == 1) {
        return std::forward<Container>(container).lower_bound(std::forward<Key>(key));
    }
    else {
        return std::end(std::forward<Container>(container));
    }
}

void do_stuff(std::set<const int*, LessPtr>& set_ptrs) {
    // auto value = string{"something"};
    auto value = 1;
    auto iter = return_iter(set_ptrs, &value);
    cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&iter) << endl;
}

int main() {
    std::set<const int*, LessPtr> set_ptrs;
    do_stuff(set_ptrs);

    return 0;
}
```

The `LessPtr` is somehow needed to cause this error..

Comment: BTW, don't do `std::end(std::forward<Container>(container))`.

Comment: @T.C. I was looking for someone to comment on that!  Could you explain why that is bad?  I was thinking about it and couldn't reach a good conclusion as to why I shouldn't do that

Comment: The free `begin` and `end` are not designed for use with rvalues and do not behave properly if given one.

Answer (score 5):

This is a libstdc++ bug in the way `std::set` handles transparent comparators. Here's a shorter example:

```
int main() {
    using S = std::set<const int*, LessPtr>;
    S set_ptrs;

    int i = 0;
    const int ci = 0;
    static_assert(std::is_same<
          decltype(set_ptrs.lower_bound(&ci)), S::iterator>{}, "!"); // OK
    static_assert(std::is_same<
          decltype(set_ptrs.lower_bound(&i)), S::iterator>{}, "!");  // Error

    return 0;
}
```

The first assertion is fine, we call `lower_bound(Key const&)`, which returns an `iterator`. The second assertion fires because we're calling the function template `template <class K> lower_bound(K const&)`, because `LessPtr` is transparent, and that overload is a better match (because it's an Exact Match), and that one, for libstdc++, is returning a `const_iterator`.

But `set_ptrs` isn't `const`, so it shouldn't be. I filed [78134](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78134)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  What is `a_tran` exactly?

Comment: I sort of still don't get it.  I think its the `std::end` which is returning the const_iterator and the call to `lower_bound` returning a regular iterator, not the other way around

Comment: @Curious It's an arbitrary identifier used to describe requirements for all the associative containers in a [large table](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#tab:containers.associative.requirements).

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure its the `end()` call thats returning the const iterator and the lower_bound returns a non const iterator.  Just wrote code to confirm that

Comment: I think the bug lies in the fact that calling the transparent comparator seems to make the return type become an `iterator` erroneously and not a `const_iterator`

Comment: Yep this is definitely a bug in the gcc implementation.  In the clang implementation seems to return a `const_iterator` for both cases correctly

Comment: @Curious Yeah already updated. Should return `iterator` in both cases, not `const_iterator`. Your `set` isn't `const`.

Comment: No, `set` isnt const but you need to return `const_iterator`s because a `set` needs only to return a const reference to its elements

Comment: Could you change your bug file to ask `lower_bound` to return a `const_iterator` in all cases?  All iterators from a set should be const

Comment: @Curious: Both kinds of iterators (`iterator` and `const_iterator`) in a set are "const" in a sense that they won't let you modify the data, but there are still two of them. And the language spec does not require them to be the same type (!): it could be the same type it could be different types. In general case you have to account for that.

Comment: @Barry if you could change your answer to reflect the fact that lower_bound with a transparent comparator returns a `iterator` and not a `const_iterator`, and that `std::end()` returns an `iterator` I will accept the answer!

Comment: @AnT yep! you are right.  But since there is a version of `const_iterator` provided by `<set>` it should use that in all places right?

Comment: @Curious What? It should return an `iterator`.

Comment: It should return a `const_iterator`  all methods to the `<set>` return a `const_iterator` at least in the clang implementation I have.  As they should right?

Comment: @Curious No...? `libc+` just has `iterator` and `const_iterator` be the same type. That's not a requirement.

Comment: @Barry So then what are you saying the error is?  Since the two iterator classes are the same then they shouldn't cause an error right?